# Copy from Excel to Browser

Tags: vba, excel, selenium

How do I "paste" in Selenium/VBA to browser textfield?

I downloaded and installed this: https://code.google.com/p/selenium-vba/

I managed to start Selenium in Firefox (CTRL-ALT-S) and recorded my steps for automation. I changed the code language to VBA in there and copied it to paste it in Excel.

For those of you who want to know what to do in Excel (2013):

> Right click "Start" 
>   Customize Ribbon
>   Check "Developer Tools" on the right 
>   Click OK > Click on "Developer Tools" > Click "Visual Basic" > Click "Extras" > Click "References" > Look for "SeleniumWrapper Type Library" and check it > Click OK > In Menu bar click on the top arrow beside "Paste UserForm" > Click "Module" > Now paste the VBA Code from Selenium (Firefox) Plugin in there

Everything works perfectly fine but I want it to do repetitive web browser tasks so it should copy Excel cells and paste it in Textboxes in Websites for example in the Google Searchbar.

I already found a solution for the copying part: 
`Range("A1").Copy`

It works but I can't find any working solution for the pasting part. Tested but didn't work:

`driver.findElementById("ID").SendKeys "^v"` gives out "v" instead of pasting.

`driver.findElementById("ID").SendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "v"));` Doesn't accept ";" and also doesn't work without.

I also tried several "Wait" and "Sleep" codes but neither do I know for sure which of them actually work nor if they are necessary.

`driver.action.key_down(: control)` Didn't work.

`driver.findElementById("ID").keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(String.valueOf('\u0076')).perform();` Syntax error, without ";" "Error: List Delimiter" and marks the "." between "String" and "value".

I am grateful for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to send the text:

```
Dim driver As New FirefoxDriver
driver.Get "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"

driver.FindElementById("searchInput").SendKeys [A1]
```

If you really need to use the clipboard:

```
Dim Keys As New Selenium.Keys
Dim driver As New Selenium.FirefoxDriver
driver.Get "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"

driver.SetClipBoard [A1]
driver.FindElementById("searchInput").SendKeys Keys.Control, "v"
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it depends on the kind of element you want to *paste* the text to, but how about just setting the element's value directly;

```
driver.findElementById("ID").text = Range("A1").value2
```