# VBA+Selenium Copy Paste

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, html-table, automation

First of all, the website I use below is just an example I took. This means I do not need to paste any data there, just testing this.

I am working on a VBA to copy and paste an table from Excel to a text box in a browser. The table is dynamic, so last row changes.

The VBA I wrote is:

```
Sub Test()

Dim obj As New WebDriver
Dim Keys As New Selenium.Keys
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Nothing

lr = Range("K" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = Range("K9:N" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    obj.Start "chrome", ""
    obj.Get "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29348045/copy-from-excel-to-browser/"

    obj.SetClipBoard [Range("K9:N" & lr)]
    obj.FindElementById("wmd-input").SendKeys Keys.Control, "v"

End Sub
```

When I tried this VBA it works fine:

```
Sub Test()

Dim obj As New WebDriver
Dim Keys As New Selenium.Keys


    obj.Start "chrome", ""
    obj.Get "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29348045/copy-from-excel-to-browser/"

    obj.SetClipBoard [K11]
    obj.FindElementById("wmd-input").SendKeys Keys.Control, "v"

 End Sub
```

On the other hand, the table contains title(column 1), day (column 2), time (column 3) and link (column 4) to some of our sessions. Do I need to convert it to html to paste the table? If not, can I paste it as a list? something like:

- Session 1. Day and Time. Link: XXX
- Session 2. Day and Time. Link: XXX
- Session 3. Day and Time. Link: XXX
- and so on

Thanks,

Comment: You could get the clipboard data and manipulate it, then set it back to the clipboard and paste it.  A text area should retain line breaks, but not a standard input.... it also depends on how the server processes the data.  Security minded sites would not allow any HTML to be stored.  Some sites might allow links but would probably have a white-list and would filter based on "reading" a URL.  (They would write the resulting HTML for the link when displaying the data.)   Maybe describe what happens with your current code?  (all one line when server displays the data?)

Comment: It seems that I am not able to copy the whole table

Comment: Debug a bit.  Is it because you're not copying all the data, or is the server or the input field losing the data?  (input fields can have limits set...)